# Iterate the dictionary and find the first failed task error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How do I find the first failed task error message in the dictionary? Task names are not consistent and can be changed.

```
{
    "status": "FAIL",
    "tasks": {
        "validate": {
            "description": "Performs the validations.",
            "task_status": "SUCCESS",
            "error": []
        },
        "storage": {
            "description": "Persist the data in mongodb.",
            "task_status": "SUCCESS",
            "error": []
        },
        "email_notification": {
            "description": "Sends email notification.",
            "task_status": "FAIL",
            "error": [{
                "default_message": "Failed to send the email notification" <--- need to find this message.
            }]
        },
        "cleanup": {
            "description": "Performs the clean up operations.",
            "task_status": "PENDING",
            "error": []
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: `next(meta['error'] for task, meta in data['tasks'].items() if meta['error'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the dictionary values and then find the 'task_status'. For example like this:

```
for i in mydict['tasks'].values():
    if i['task_status'] == "FAIL":
        print(i["error"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access value with key in dictionary. [See HERE.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Lets say given information is stored in **details** variable.

```
for key, value in details['tasks'].items():
    error = value['error']

    if error:
        print(error)
```

Comment: Task names can be changed. So I am thinking of not hardcoding the task names.

Comment: In dictionaries you must know the key to get its respective value. So, I think there is no way to do extract value with dynamic keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
print(next(filter(lambda e: len(e['error']) > 0,
    data['tasks'].values()))['error'][0]['default_message'])
```

Full example below:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVNNS8NAEL3nVwy5JIFSCt4KCqJVClIKwVMIYdtM2sVkN@xMRJH@9rjZhraxovVgYC9v5n3M7qR@561WV22bYwFoTFbRJswFi2jqgf0McmMUKHzjsJAlowlLUa1yATiFElWISWBp2gRpBDcwGUFHTgIW9EJBOn4VZYMURlF06EsmaRJYO9GUnFVIJDYYpJ7XEeEaPpyvTyy4IX8K/sPt/Mkf7VEna8F9k4Osg7RUHKCukiOtjaxZatXpLNEU2lQEvEXoWbZE4178wOtMsqN//Hx3N4vjr11uGltP0gO@O7bY/NrYwS5JRZLYhXI3IBVUWm10vvqfYFgJWWZKsyzkWvQxfs4Yo8oJHBFOib8FPHm583RDy952sBROwnpiDqyBbAh3S@c5/IHU7vu51yUK1dR/WxNHgqYGXaO5bF2Ws8X9fPF4yat43dl5Xm2k4nDw90Ve234C)

```
def err_msg(data):
    return next(filter(lambda e: len(e['error']) > 0,
        data['tasks'].values()))['error'][0]['default_message']

data = {
    "status": "FAIL",
    "tasks": {
        "validate": {
            "description": "Performs the validations.",
            "task_status": "SUCCESS",
            "error": []
        },
        "storage": {
            "description": "Persist the data in mongodb.",
            "task_status": "SUCCESS",
            "error": []
        },
        "email_notification": {
            "description": "Sends email notification.",
            "task_status": "FAIL",
            "error": [{
                "default_message": "Failed to send the email notification"
            }]
        },
        "cleanup": {
            "description": "Performs the clean up operations.",
            "task_status": "PENDING",
            "error": []
        }
  }
}

print(err_msg(data))
```

Output:

```
Failed to send the email notification
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
data = {
    "status": "FAIL",
    "tasks": {
        "validate": {
            "description": "Performs the validations.",
            "task_status": "SUCCESS",
            "error": []
        },
        "storage": {
            "description": "Persist the data in mongodb.",
            "task_status": "SUCCESS",
            "error": []
        },
        "email_notification": {
            "description": "Sends email notification.",
            "task_status": "FAIL",
            "error": [{
                "default_message": "Failed to send the email notification"
            }]
        },
        "cleanup": {
            "description": "Performs the clean up operations.",
            "task_status": "PENDING",
            "error": [{'default_message':'Diso'}]
        }
  }
}

for sub_task in data['tasks']:
    dic_error_msg=data['tasks'][sub_task]['error']
    if len(dic_error_msg)>0:
        error_msg=dic_error_msg[0]['default_message']
        print(error_msg)
```